# The bound for the probability of maximum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have a small question that as for a fixed number $c$, and random variables $X_i$, $Y_i$ for i=1,2...,n, we know that $|P(X_i<c)-P(Y_i<c)| \leq \alpha$ holds true for any $i$, where $\alpha$ is a constant. Then what is upper bound for $|P(\max_i X_i<c)-P(\max_i Y_i<c)|$. Here, $X_i$ are not i.i.d, and $Y_i$ are also not i.i.d.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is anything known about their distribution or correlation? (since you said they are not i.i.d.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get any nice bound in terms of $\alpha.$  Here is an example where $\alpha = 0$ but $|P(\max X_i < c)-P(\max Y_i < c)| > 0$.

Let $X_0$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{P}(X_0 = c) = p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_0 = -c) = 1-p$ for some $p \in (0,1)$, and let $X_1=X_0$, $X_2 = -X_0$.  Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be independent copies of $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively.  Then clearly $|P(X_i < c) - P(Y_i < c)| = 0$ for each $i$, but $P(\max_i X_i < c) = 0$ and $P(\max_i Y_i < c) = p(1-p)$ so $|P(\max_i X_i < c) - P(\max_i Y_i < c)| = p(1-p) > 0$.